# Данные JSON из Web API в базу SQL

Tags: c#, sql, json, asp.net-core

Проблема следующая: есть Web API, который предоставляет данные в формате JSON (на странице также требуется ввести логин-пароль). Необходимо преобразовать полученные данные в SQL-таблицу, чтобы затем делать к ней запросы из веб-приложения. 
Я пишу веб-приложение ASP .NET Core в среде Visual Studio, различные интернет-источники подсказывают, что описанные действия возможно реализовать посредством компонента SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS). К сожалению, у меня нет опыта работы с данным компонентом, а найти толковую инструкцию конкретно для моего случая не удалось.
Если кто-либо уже сталкивался с подобной задачей: какие действия можно предпринять? Либо же стоит рассмотреть работу с JSON-данными непосредственно в веб-приложении?

Comment: вы можете десериализовать данные и записать из в таблицу с нужной структурой с помощью Entity Framework

Comment: Во-первых, укажите конкретную СУБД (в том числе - точную версию). Во-вторых, сейчас практически любая современная СУБД умеет хранить и обрабатывать JSON (другое дело, насколько эффективно - но в любом случае парсинг средствами СУБД всего массива данных при вставке будет быстрее парсинга на клиенте и поштучной вставки), так что клиенту достаточно отдать полученный JSON серверу как есть, и затем обращаться за уже раскиданными данными.

Comment: У меня развернута база SQL в Azure. Касаемо обработки JSON непосредственно в СУБД - читал, что можно реализовать посредством SQL CLR, но такой метод описывают как крайне нежелательный.

Comment: @KuzCode а где можно более подробно про это узнать?

Comment: @witchgen про EF [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/)